# Ant standard tasks

Tags: java, maven-2, ant, task

Maven has a fairly standardized project structure and standard plugins for compilation and testing. Is there something widespread for Ant?

I found the following projects so far:

- [Antiplate](http://antiplate.origo.ethz.ch/)
- [Ant Script Library](http://www.exubero.com/asl/)

But I'm not sure whether these are widespread and are likely to be maintained in the future. Does someone have experience with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the guy who wrote Ant Script Library.  He doesn't have any intention of stopping.  To me, Ant's flexibility makes it hard for things like this to succeed.  Ant-contrib only makes it worse IMHO as it allows people to break the model of the tool.  Shame, as Ant is phenomenally powerful if you use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of them.  I've been on 2 significant Java projects lately. Our ant tasks were simple and home-grown.  Each time someone starts a new project they make a copy of the ant file and mostly just change some constants at the top.